# Mongoose: How to 'schedule' the update of access token (in our database), using refresh token?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, passport.js, node-cron

**Flow:**

- User attempts to login via Spotify (OAuth), and grants access to our web app (nodejs).
- `accessToken`, `refreshToken`, `expires_in` and `profile` data is returned in exchange for the Authorization Code. *(using Passport.js)*
- `accessToken`, `refreshToken` and some other data is stored on mongoDb Atlas (cloud), forming a Document. *(using mongoose)*
- The user logs out.
- The same user logs back in.
- `accessToken`, `refreshToken`, `expires_in` and `profile` data is returned in exchange for the Authorization Code.
- The Document in the cloud database, gets updated.

We are using these access tokens to create API calls in our main application `app.js`.

---

**passport-setup.js:** This file is 'required' in `app.js`.

```js
const passport = require("passport");
const SpotifyStrategy = require("passport-spotify").Strategy;
const keys = require("./keys");
const User = require("../models/user-model");

// Creating cookie
passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user.id);
})

// Acccessing the created cookie
passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
  User.findById(id).then((user) => {
    done(null, user);
  })
})

passport.use(
  new SpotifyStrategy({
    // Options for Spotify Strategy
    clientID: keys.spotify.clientID,
    clientSecret: keys.spotify.clientSecret,
    callbackURL: "/auth/spotify/redirect"
  }, (accessToken, refreshToken, expires_in, profile, done) => {
    // Passport callback function
    console.log("Reached Passport callback function, inside of 'passport-setup.js'.");

    // Check if user already exists in our database or if there is need to create a new one.
    User.findOneAndUpdate({
        spotifyId: profile.id
      }, {
        $set: {
          accessToken: accessToken,
          refreshToken: refreshToken
        }
      }, {
        new: true,
        useFindAndModify: false
      }).then((existingUser) => {
        if (existingUser) {
          console.log("User already exists in database. Latest record:");
          console.log(existingUser);
          done(null, existingUser);
        } else {
          new User({
            displayName: profile.displayName,
            email: profile._json.email,
            spotifyId: profile.id,
            accessToken: accessToken,
            refreshToken: refreshToken
          }).save().then((newUser) => {
            console.log("New user created:");
            console.log(newUser);
            done(null, newUser);
          }).catch((err) => {
            console.log("Error occured: " + err);
          })
        }
      })
  })
)
```

---

**Drawback:**

The access token expires in an hour. To make more of the API calls, he need to re-login.

**Update required for the application:**

The refresh token should update the value of access token, in our database, every hour. (This should happen only for as long as the user stays logged in.)

---

**This is what I'm aware of:**

- Fetch access token using refresh token:

```js
axios({
  url: "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token",
  method: "post",
  params: {
    grant_type: "refresh_token",
    refresh_token:                    // Please guide how to input the refresh token here.
  },
  headers: {
    Authorization: authorization,
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  }
}).then(function(response) {
  // console.log(response.data);
  // console.log(response.data.access_token);
  access_token = response.data.access_token;
  token = "Bearer " + access_token;
  console.log(token);
}).catch(function(error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

- For scheduling, we can use node-crone:

```js
cron.schedule('*/59 * * * *', () => {
   
    // Our task here, that we want to repeat 59th minute of every hour. We can also modify '59'. It's not necessary to have '59' only.
}
```

---

How to put the above two, together?

Where do we need to put the scheduled code - In `passport-setup.js` or `app.js`, or someplace else?